# Generic array which takes first elements type

Tags: typescript

There was this [challenge](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00014-easy-first/README.md)

> Implement a generic First that takes an Array T and returns its
> first element's type.

```
type arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
type arr2 = [3, 2, 1];

type head1 = First<arr1>; // expected to be 'a'
type head2 = First<arr2>; // expected to be 3
```

But I am confused. Since the tasks says we should return **first elements type**, shouldn't return in first case be `string`? and in second `number`?

What am I missing?

Ps. This is the given solution and it indeed returns "a" instead of string

```
type First<T extends any[]> = T extends [] ? never : T[0];
```

---

**Update**:

In below code `head1` is inferred as `string`.

```
let arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"]; // use let instead of type
type head1 = First<typeof arr1>;
```

Why when I used `type array1` as in my question, `head1` was inferred as "a" and above as "string"?

Comment: The title doesn't seem to have much to do with your question, which is apparently a confusion around [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  And I would expect `type First<T extends any[]> = T[0]` to be the canonical answer to that question.

Comment: @jcalz that won't work with empty array. But as the original problem is framed, shouldn't it return 'string'  instead of 'a'?

Comment: "that won't work with empty array".  I don't know what you mean by "empty array"; if you mean "empty *tuple*, like `First<[]>`, then it returns `undefined` which is very much the correct answer.  And no, it should return `"a"`.  I think maybe you are confusing values and types.  `type Arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"]` is a tuple *type*, not a value.  It describes an array whose first element is literally the string `"a"`, second is `"b"`, etc.  The first element of that tuple type is `"a"`, not `string`.  One is a subtype of the other but they are not the same.

Comment: I think maybe your confusion comes from the fact that there is a difference between TS types and values. Types get erased from compilation to JS, while values generally persist.  Your entire example code would get compiled to an empty JS file. There's no array value, just a type.   If I write `const x: ["a", "b", "c"] = ["a", "b", "c"]` then the thing after the `:` is a type and the thing after the `=` is a value; they happen to be written the same but they are different.  `First<typeof x>` is `"a"`. If you write `const y: string[] = ["a", "b", "c"]` then `First<typeof y>` should be `string`.

Comment: @jcalz Please see my update. When I used `let arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"];` and passed that to `First` now it returned `string`. What did I confuse?

Comment: @jcalz Ah I think what you mean is here `type arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"];` This is actually a Tuple, whose first element if of type "a" right? Hm.... Btw here is link to solution if you are interested: https://ghaiklor.github.io/type-challenges-solutions/en/easy-first.html

Comment: What you wrote is that previous comment is correct, but I think you might still not understand the difference between types and values in TypeScript, and I don't know how to help you with that any further here.  Good luck!

Comment: @guest The type that you want is probably something like this: [`type First<T extends readonly [any, ...any[]]> = T[0]`](https://tsplay.dev/wQ38jm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that `arr1` and `arr2` aren't array types; they're [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types). In JavaScript, tuples are simply arrays, but in TypeScript's type system every element of a tuple has its own type.

This is easier to see if you use "actual" types instead of literals, for example:

```
type arr1 = [string, number, Object];

const arr1Value: arr1 = ["hello", 42, {}];

type head1 = First<arr1>; // string
```

Note that `arr1` *is not an array*. It's a *type* of array (or tuple), and `arr1Value` is an array of that type.

If you don't provide the type of an array literal, it is inferred:

```
let arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"]; // arr1 is of type string[]
```

Now, the inferred type of `arr1` could have been inferred as `['a', 'b', 'c']`; that is, a tuple of those three strings. But that's almost never what you want: for example, it wouldn't let you push more values onto the array. So TypeScript infers that it's a `string[]` instead. (If you do want to infer a tuple type, add `as const` at the end.)

Comment: I think OP here doesn't understand that `arr1` and `arr2` are *types* and not *values*.

Comment: @jcalz Could be. In that case zaxanq's answer will help :)

Comment: I think you are still not understanding the difference between values and types and I don't think a comment on someone's answer is a great place to explore followup questions, sorry.

Comment: @Thomas I updated my question. Can you see the **update** and maybe put that in your answer too?

Comment: Array literals are not inferred as tuple types.

Comment: Added some more, hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: @Thomas I see so basically since in first case it was `type arr1 = ["a"]` typescript inferred the types differently vs `let arr1=["a"]` right?

Comment: In the first case there is no type inference. There is a type declaration. You are _telling_ `TypeScript` what the type is; it doesn't need to try and infer anything. In the second case, there is a variable declaration without a type, so TypeScript needs to figure out what the type of the variable is.

Comment: @Thomas I see so first case is Tuple type with first element of type "a". The latter is `string[]`? Ok I think it is more clear thanks

Comment: But it was also confusing in the challenge how they used Array keyword all the time (https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00014-easy-first/README.md). Ok thanks

Comment: Yes, that is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Type in TypeScript doesn't necessarily have to be `string`. It is a valid type, however very general.

You can limit the possible strings to say just `'a'`, `'b'` or `'c'` using:

```
type Abc = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
```

If you now create a variable with this type declared, you will get compilation error whenever incorrect value is defined:

```
const name: Abc = 'John'; // TypeScript will mark this as incorrect
```

Now, to provide you with the solution, apparently this is enough:

```
type First<T extends any[]> = T[0];
```